# qemu-system-aarch64 memory and device layout

Tags: memory-management, qemu, arm64, mmu

Is there any document about the memory and device layout of qemu-arm64.

I can get some information from atf and linux kernel.

Since the memory size can be specificated. What's the actual phys address of memory.

eg:
-m 2G

Is the memory from [0~2G）
And where to find the io address? eg uart gic

Answer (score 1):

For all QEMU's system emulation, the layout of memory and devices depends on the machine you ask it to emulate. This differs across architectures, obviously, and also between machine types within an architecture. (Some architectures are more consistent than others because that's how the real world hardware is : almost all x86 machines are "looks like a PC"; but every 32-bit arm board is different from the others in major ways. QEMU's machine models look like the real hardware, generally.)

So the answer to your question depends upon the machine type:

1. For machine types which match real hardware (e.g. "xlnx-zcu102") you need to find and read the documentation and data sheets of that hardware.
2. For machine types which don't match real hardware and exist only in QEMU (e.g. "sbsa-ref" or "virt"), this information should be documented in QEMU's documentation, but often is not.

The answer for the "virt" board, incidentally, is:

- flash memory is at 0x0000_0000
- RAM starts at 0x4000_0000
- to find the address of all other devices, the guest should read the device-tree-blob (dtb) which QEMU creates and puts into the guest memory. For a bare-metal guest image the dtb can be found at the base of RAM; for a Linux-kernel-boot-protocol guest image, the dtb address is passed in the usual way for the Linux kernel.

Update: I added documentation for the 'virt' board to QEMU, including the info about bare-metal programming: https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/arm/virt.html#hardware-configuration-information-for-bare-metal-programming

Comment: Thanks for letting me know "virt" is a board.
Take a look at the https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/hw/arm/virt.c
It shows:
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Peter Maydell for letting me know "virt" is a board.
Take a look at the https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/hw/arm/virt.c
It shows:

```
static const MemMapEntry base_memmap[] = {
    /* Space up to 0x8000000 is reserved for a boot ROM */
    [VIRT_FLASH] =              {          0, 0x08000000 },
    [VIRT_CPUPERIPHS] =         { 0x08000000, 0x00020000 },
    /* GIC distributor and CPU interfaces sit inside the CPU peripheral space */
    [VIRT_GIC_DIST] =           { 0x08000000, 0x00010000 },
    [VIRT_GIC_CPU] =            { 0x08010000, 0x00010000 },
    [VIRT_GIC_V2M] =            { 0x08020000, 0x00001000 },
    [VIRT_GIC_HYP] =            { 0x08030000, 0x00010000 },
    [VIRT_GIC_VCPU] =           { 0x08040000, 0x00010000 },
    /* The space in between here is reserved for GICv3 CPU/vCPU/HYP */
    [VIRT_GIC_ITS] =            { 0x08080000, 0x00020000 },
    /* This redistributor space allows up to 2*64kB*123 CPUs */
    [VIRT_GIC_REDIST] =         { 0x080A0000, 0x00F60000 },
    [VIRT_UART] =               { 0x09000000, 0x00001000 },
    [VIRT_RTC] =                { 0x09010000, 0x00001000 },
    [VIRT_FW_CFG] =             { 0x09020000, 0x00000018 },
    [VIRT_GPIO] =               { 0x09030000, 0x00001000 },
    [VIRT_SECURE_UART] =        { 0x09040000, 0x00001000 },
    [VIRT_SMMU] =               { 0x09050000, 0x00020000 },
    [VIRT_PCDIMM_ACPI] =        { 0x09070000, MEMORY_HOTPLUG_IO_LEN },
    [VIRT_ACPI_GED] =           { 0x09080000, ACPI_GED_EVT_SEL_LEN },
    [VIRT_NVDIMM_ACPI] =        { 0x09090000, NVDIMM_ACPI_IO_LEN},
    [VIRT_MMIO] =               { 0x0a000000, 0x00000200 },
    /* ...repeating for a total of NUM_VIRTIO_TRANSPORTS, each of that size */
    [VIRT_PLATFORM_BUS] =       { 0x0c000000, 0x02000000 },
    [VIRT_SECURE_MEM] =         { 0x0e000000, 0x01000000 },
    [VIRT_PCIE_MMIO] =          { 0x10000000, 0x2eff0000 },
    [VIRT_PCIE_PIO] =           { 0x3eff0000, 0x00010000 },
    [VIRT_PCIE_ECAM] =          { 0x3f000000, 0x01000000 },
    /* Actual RAM size depends on initial RAM and device memory settings */
    [VIRT_MEM] =                { GiB, LEGACY_RAMLIMIT_BYTES },
};
```

Comment: This is indeed the data structure where QEMU internally defines where various devices live for this board. However guest code should not rely on this internal implementation information -- it might change in a future QEMU version. The device tree blob is what guest code should read to find out these addresses.